# Alternative to AWS Cognito Paris Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS architecture which using API Gateway and Lambda Authorizer. Problem is that region I'm choosing is Paris and AWS Cognito is not available in this region.
Can I be able to use AWS Cognito in a different region (Frankfurt)?
I was looking at an alternative like Auth0, Okta but they are pricy.
Any suggestion.

PS: Anyone knows when Cognito will be available in Paris Region

Comment: Sure, you should be able to use Amazon Cognito in a different region. Let us know if you find any problems.

Comment: But this not be cost-efficient?.

Comment: Amazon Cognito is priced the same in all regions (according to the [Amazon Cognito pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/)).